# WPF ListView alter foreground using codebehind for just a cell

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, code-behind

Hi I have a `listview` with two columns, "*Folder*" & "*Status*". How do I change the foreground of the "*Status*" members to green if its data is "*Locked*" and to red if its data is "*Unlocked*".

Example

```
Folder    |       Status
----------+--------------------------------------------
xxxx      |       Locked  <--To be appeared as green
yyyyy     |       Unlocked <-- To be appeared as red
```

Sorry for my bad english.

EDIT:---------------------------------

Hey i tried your solution but i still cant get it to work.

Take a look at what i done wrong.

```
<ListView x:Name="FoldersListView" Margin="11,202,8,98" Foreground="Black" Background="#FFFFCFCF" BorderBrush="Transparent" FontWeight="Bold">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Folder" Width="300" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path = FolderPath}"/>

                <GridViewColumn Header="Status" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path = FolderStatus}">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate> 
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Locked}"> 
                                <TextBlock.Style> 
                                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock"> 
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/> 
                                        <Style.Triggers> 
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Locked}" Value="True"> 
                                                  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/> 
                                            </DataTrigger> 
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Locked}" Value="False"> 
                                                  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/> 
                                            </DataTrigger> 
                                        </Style.Triggers> 
                                    </Style> 
                           </TextBlock.Style> 
                          </TextBlock> 
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
```

Comment: You should remove DisplayMemberBinding from the second column and add the following for TextBlock's Text property {Binding Path = FolderStatus}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use triggers for a particular CellTemplate

```
<DataTemplate> 
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Status}"> 
 <TextBlock.Style> 
   <Style TargetType="TextBlock"> 
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/> 
     <Style.Triggers> 
       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Locked}" Value="True"> 
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/> 
        </DataTrigger> 
       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Locked}" Value="False"> 
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/> 
        </DataTrigger> 
      </Style.Triggers> 
     </Style> 
   </TextBlock.Style> 
  </TextBlock> 
<DataTemplate>
```

**UPDATE**

I just saw you asked for the solution using an imperative code. Therefore, you can ignore my answer which is a solution for a declaritive way.

Please however note that the goal you are trying to achieve should not be implemented in code behind as it's not consistent with the MVVM principles

Comment: Just as a note, he doesn't say he's using the MVVM pattern. WPF was intended to be used with MVVM, but it doesn't have to be, by any means.

Comment: @reviouser - I agree with you. I just wanted to mention about good habit